# Is there something inaccurate about this implementation of a 2-d rotation in numpy?

Tags: python-2.7, numpy, rotational-matrices

I've been scratching my head about the accuracy of a 2-d rotation in numpy. The implementation is textbook, and my application calls for a left-handed system, so:

```
from numpy import sin, cos

def rotate(pathx, pathy, r):
    """
    pathx and pathy are lists of np.float64's recording x and y 
    coordinates of points to be rotated
    """
    c = cos(r)
    s = sin(r)
    pathx = c*pathx + s*pathy
    pathy = -s*pathx + c*pathy
```

To test this, I fed in `pathx=[1]` and `pathy=[1]` and `r=arctan2(1,1)~=pi/4~=0.78539816339744828` with the expected outcome that the vector (1,1) would be aligned with the x-axis after being rotated by `pi/4`

I get `[1.4142135623730949, -0.29289321881345221]`. The reason this seems absurd is because I expected something *much* closer to `0.0` on the y coordinate. I also tried boosting things by making both the inputs and the sin, cos and arctan2 output all `dtype=float64`, but it made no difference.

Am I making some foolish mistake? Or is there some numerical instability I should have anticipated? I just can't believe the magnitude of the error...

Answer (score 2):

When you assign

```
pathy = -s*pathx + c*pathy
```

this is now using the `pathx` variable that you *just* assigned, which was already rotated. You want to be using the array that was originally passed to the function as `pathx`, before rotation.

Correspondingly, an easy fix maintaining your current approach would be

```
def rotate(pathx, pathy, r):
    c = np.cos(r)
    s = np.sin(r)
    pathx_new = c * pathx + s * pathy
    pathy_new =-s * pathx + c * pathy
    return pathx_new, pathy_new
```

which for your example case returns

```
(array([ 1.41421356]), array([  1.11022302e-16]))
```

Comment: ugh! That's it! Looking at all the wrong places. Thanks for your help getting my stupid noggin turned around.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe this will make sense of the error:

```
pathx_new =  c*pathx      + s*pathy
pathy     = -s*pathx_new  + c*pathy
```

basically, you're updating `pathx` and defining `pathy` based on its new value

You want to do this, for in-place reassignment (harder than I expected actually):

```
def rotate(pathxy, r):
    """
    pathx and pathy are lists of np.float64's recording x and y 
    coordinates of points to be rotated
    """
    c = np.cos(r)
    s = np.sin(r)
    rot = np.array([[c, s], [-s, c]]).T
    pathxy.dot(rot, out = pathxy)

pathxy = np.array([pathx, pathy]).T.astype(float)
```

then for `pathx = pathy = 1`,

```
rotate(pathxy, 0.78539816339744828)
array([ 1.41421356,  0.        ])
```

and for `pathxy = np.ones((3,2))`

```
rotate(pathxy, 0.78539816339744828)

pathxy

array([[ 1.41421356,  0.        ],
       [ 1.41421356,  0.        ],
       [ 1.41421356,  0.        ]])
```

Comment: Thanks for the interesting in-place numpy idiom. I might like to do that actually. In general pathx and pathy could be very long.